# hibernate with c3p0 opening multiple PooledDataSource's unnecessarily

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, c3p0

A component of my standalone java 8 application uses hibernate-c3p0 4.2.17.Final with a dependency on c3p0 0.9.21. This connects to an SQL Server 2014 database using jtds.

These are older versions however to upgrade at present will require some code changes so it's not possible.

The issue is with the c3p0 PooledDataSource's that are created whilst under load. On my performance server a single PooledDataSource is created (as viewed via jconsole)
however at a clients linux site I am seeing 18 PooledDataSources.

I understand that multiple PooledDataSources can be created if the connection is made with difference user credentials, but this is not the case. the hibernate conf used for the pool size is:

```
min pool size​
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
max pool size
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
```

On system start-up there is a single pool but under load this goes up to 18.

So questions are:

```
1. Why the multiple pools from the same configuration?
2. Does hibernate/c3p0 create a new PooledDataSource under load?
3. Under what scenarios might this happen?
```

Comment: How many connections are open to the SQL server in this situation? And are you certain you are seeing pools and not just the objects connected to this pool?

Comment: the connections seen in the database hit about 100, despite the 20 limit. These are stable at 100 over the duration of the test cycles. How would I know if it were a pool or objects connected to the pool. I understood for a datasource there would be a single PooledDataSource, unless there were multiple getConnections with different user credentials.

Comment: Even if you had different auth (user/password), there would be only one `PooledDataSource`. Each auth would have a separate pool within the `PooledDataSource`. If via JMX you are seeing 18, your application is likely doing something to create 18 distinct `SessionFactory` (in native hibernate-speak) objects (these wrap the `DataSource` from which Session/Connections are drawn. What your application is doing to create multiple `SessionFactory` objects I can't say.

Comment: I'll take a look at that tomorrow, a very good pointer thanks @steve

Comment: @SteveWaldman interesting. reviewing the SessionFactory code it looks like we require connections to 3 different databases. We hold a map of environment name to SessionFactory, so each db has a separate SessionFactory. when a connection is needed we access the map and retrieve the relevant SessionFactory. From what you're saying there should only be a single SessionFactory from which you retrieve a particular PooledDataSource by username. Would this be correct?

Comment: additionally from the reading i'm doing around this it's normal to have a SessionFactory per database connectivity required. Is this not the case?

Comment: You might need multiple SessionFactories for some reason, I don't know the architecture of your application, but yeah, typically there'd just be one for a single database and authentication, which under the covers would manage a `PooledDataSouce` if you've configured hibernate to use c3p0. But it sounds like there was a reason someone defined multiple environments and perhaps configurations for different SessionFactories. Nothing wrong with that if the reason is good. I'd try to understand why things are set up as they are, and then decide whether a simpler, more typical approach would work.